# Necessity and sufficiency on dead end worlds in Kripke's model

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

Suppose we are evaluating $\square p$, $\diamondsuit$p, $\square\square$p, $\diamondsuit\diamondsuit$p, $\square$$\diamondsuit$p,  $\diamondsuit$$\square$p on a dead end world (the world that can't reach any further worlds). Are all of these trivially true or are some of them false, and if so, why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try thinking about specifically $\Box p$ and $\Diamond p$. What do you think each one says intuitively? And, what do you know about quantification over the emptyset? (Once you understand these the others will follow more easily.)

Comment: Can a "dead end" world in your sense reach itself (you talk about not reaching any *further* worlds)? That will make a difference.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, intuitively I think that $\diamondsuit p$ on a dead end world would be false since we can't find any world that can be reached from a dead end world in which p is true. Also, I think that $\square p$ would be true, since there is no world that can be reached from a dead end world in which p is false so $\square p$ is true.

Comment: @PeterSmith no, "dead end" world can't reach itself.

Comment: Then @NoahShweber has indeed given you the clue to the answer, and your response shows that you've got the hint :)

Comment: @Glavatar You're exactly on the right track. Now can you figure out (say) $\Diamond\Box p$?

Comment: @NoahScweber Yes I can (I suppose $\Diamond\Box p$ is false). Thank you very much for helping me understand this :)